# Move method of worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to arrange tabs within workbook using the coding found online as below, however, after arranging some of the sheets within the workbook, the following error arises "Run-time error '1004'; Move method of worksheet class failed. I have stepped through the macro several times and it seems to work fine until it comes across a sheet that has not been renamed. That's when the error crops up. The line this occurs on is `Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)`

The coding is as follows:

```
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you put this code ? You need to add new module and put the code. It work for me

Comment: Try using fully qualified references: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)`. This sort of error could occur if you have multiple workbooks open at the same time. In short, put `ThisWorkbook` in front of all `Sheets` objects in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it, but based on your existing method:

```
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook

'
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")

   For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To .Sheets.Count - 1

        Set sht1 = .Sheets(j)
        Set sht2 = .Sheets(j + 1)

        '
        ' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
        '
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(sht1.Name) > UCase$(sht2.Name) Then
               sht1.Move After:=sht2
            End If
        '
        ' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
        '
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(sht1.Name) < UCase$(sht2.Name) Then
               sht1.Move After:=sht2
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i

End With

End Sub
```

From comments: There were other sheets that were hidden using `xlSheetVeryHidden`, hence the initial run-time error in the question.

Comment: Thanks CLR that worked fine. Your coding helped me find out the initial problem ... there were other sheets that were hidden using xlSheetVeryHidden, hence the initial run-time error.

Comment: @BaberBeg I have edited your comment into the answer for posterity.  The actual root cause you found is very helpful for debugging.